# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В блок форума IPB добавил небольшой JS следующего содержания:

```html
var Events = {};

Events.text = [
 ['Начнётся через', '<font color="green">Открыт, до начала</font>'],
 ['Появится через', '<font color="red">Торопись, осталось</font>']
];

Events.sked = [
  ['Информация 1',          0,      '08:40', '02:30', '04:30', '06:30', '08:30', '10:30', '12:30', '14:30', '16:30', '18:30', '20:30', '22:30', ],
  ['Информация 2',          0,      '01:00', '05:00', '09:00', '13:00', '17:00', '21:00'],
  ['Информация ',          0,      '01:30', '03:30', '05:30', '07:30', '09:30', '11:30', '13:30', '15:30', '17:30', '19:30', '21:30', '23:30'], 
  ['Информация 3',        0,      '02:00', '06:00', '10:00', '14:00', '18:00', '22:00'],
  ['Информация 4',         0,      '02:30', '08:30', '14:30', '20:30'],
  ['Информация ',             0,      '20:00'],
  ['Информация 5',     1,      '02:15', '06:15', '10:15', '14:15', '18:15', '22:15'],
  ['Информация 6',    1,      '02:30', '08:30', '14:30', '20:30'],
  ['Информация 7',    1,      '02:40', '06:40', '10:40', '14:40', '18:40', '22:40'],
  ['Информация 8',               1,      '04:30', '12:30', '23:59'],
];

Events.init = function (e) {

        if (typeof e == "string") 
        var g = new Date(new Date().toString().replace(/\date('H')+:\date('i')+:\date('s')+/g, e));
        var f = (typeof e == "number" ? e : (g.getHours() * 60 + g.getMinutes()) * 60 + g.getSeconds()), q = Events.sked, j = [];       
        
        for (var a = 0; a < q.length; a++) {
                var n = q[a];
                for (var k = 2; k < q[a].length; k++) {
                        var b = 0, p = q[a][k].split(":"), o = (p[0] * 60 + p[1] * 1) * 60, c = q[a][2].split(":");
                        if (q[a].length - 1 == k && (o - f) < 0) b = 1;
                        var r = b ? (1440 * 60 - f) + ((c[0] * 60 + c[1] * 1) * 60) : o - f;
                        if (f <= o || b) {
                                var l = Math.floor((r / 60) / 60), l = l < 10 ? "0" + l : l, d = Math.floor((r / 60) % 60), d = d < 10 ? "0" + d : d, u = r % 60, u = u < 10 ? "0" + u : u;
                                j.push('<div class="event_title">' + '<b><span>' + q[a][b ? 2 : k] + "</span></b><b>" + n[0] + '</b></div><div class="event_info"><span>' + (l + ":" + d + ":" + u) + '</span>' + (Events.text[q[a][1]][+(l == 0 && d < (q[a][1] ? 1 : 5))]) + "</div>");
        break;
                        };
                };
        };
        document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = j.join("");
        setTimeout(function () {
                Events.init(f == 86400 ? 1 : ++f);
        }, 1000);
};
```

Сам код из блока вызывается следующим путём:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploads/events.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">Events.init('00:00');</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё работает как нужно, но как только перехожу в какую-либо тему на форуме - получаю в консоли ошибку **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"**, ну и само собой JS отказывается работать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Люди добрые, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, ибо я от JS очень далёк.

Comment: Пробовали открывать файл events.js в браузере напрямую?

Comment: В приведенном коде нету такой синтаксической ошибки. Смотрите файл `uploads/events.js` на наличие ошибок